# Delay onload of script till promise is finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is there a way to delay the onload event of a script tag, till some Promise in the script is fullfilled?

A little bit background: I load a script with the following function. Inside the script some async function is invoked which returns a value.

```js
const loadScript = (src, resolveWithGlobal) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      resolve(window[resolveWithGlobal]);
    };

    window.document.body.appendChild(script);
});

const lib = await loadScript("path/to/library1.js", "library2");
```

And the loaded script looks similar to this one (it behaves like a proxy to load some other script/library)

```js
// library1.js
(async () => {
   await loadScript("path/to/library2.js", "library2");
})();
```

Currently I just return were to lookup and do two `loadScript` calls in the same file, which is kind of ugly if I later want to remove the indirection

```
const lib1 = loadScript("lib1.js", "lib1");
const lib = loadScript(lib.path, "lib2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general case, you can put the resolver function onto the window, with some name that won't collide with any others - perhaps put a random string into the dataset of the script tag. Then have the script, when it runs, check its script tag for the unique name and call the resolver when its asynchronous action is done..

```
const loadScript = (src, resolveWithGlobal) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        const script = window.document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        const uniqueId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        script.dataset.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        window[uniqueId] = () => {
            delete window[uniqueId]
            return () => {
                resolve(window[resolveWithGlobal]);
            };
        };
        script.onload = () => {
            // If resolver hasn't been retrieved by the library, do it now:
            window[uniqueId]?.()();
        };

        window.document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
```

```
const lib1 = loadScript("lib1.js", "lib1");
```

```
// lib1.js
const resolve = window[document.currentScript.uniqueid]();
loadScript("path/to/library2.js", "library2")
  .then(resolve);
```

If a script doesn't do anything asynchronous, it doesn't need to do anything special with regards to the resolver on the window - `loadScript` will call it instead, in such a case, when the script loads.